# Habría que hacer [tabla] rasa con las etiquetas

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Hay bastante follón con las etiquetas de nombre **tabl** y no sé por dónde hay que empezar, pero claramente hay redundancias:

- [table](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) 58 preguntas
- [tablas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablas) 165
- [html-tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-tabla) 104
- [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) 759 y tiene [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) como sinónima
- [datatable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) 183

¿Qué proponéis?

Lo único que veo claro es que estas dos deberían ser la misma:

- [bootstraptable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstraptable) 23
- [bootstrap-table](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-table) 16

Y ya que estamos, unir estas:

- [animación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animaci%c3%b3n) 76
- [animation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation) 17
- [animacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animacion) 6

y según cómo también [animated](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animated) (10) y [animate.css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animate.css) (14), [animación-css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animaci%c3%b3n-css) (2).

Y añado otra:

- [linux-mint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) 28
- [linuxmint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linuxmint) 9

Creo que la que tiene guion es la que debería quedar como primaria.

Comment: Personalmente las dos primeras las eliminaría de la faz de la tierra, dado que son excesivamente genéricas y no aportan nada. Las otras yo las veo correctas, aluden a conceptos claros dentro de su lenguaje. En cuanto a las de bootstrap, y animacion, totalmente de acuerdo. Hay que ponerse de acuerdo en cual dejar como principal

Comment: @Pikoh ¿en qué contexto se usa [tag:datatable]? Veo muchas preguntas de [tag:c#] que la usan. La pena es que se parece demasiado a [tag:datatables] de jQuery. Lo mismo se podría poner [tag:jquery-datatables] como primaria.

Comment: Efectivamente, `DataTable` tiene sentido en el contexto de .net, es una clase del framework. Pero tienes razón que en muchas preguntas parece hacer referencia a jquery, o incluso a preguntas no relacionadas con ninguno de los dos. Es posible que el primer paso fuera definir una orientación de uso para esta etiqueta, que ahora mismo no tiene.

Comment: El problema con las etiquetas es quienes preguntan no las conocen, y quienes las conocen, no preguntan. Las etiquetas son un gran saco (2.400!) desordenado, sin estructura, organización ni agrupación. Creo que sería mejor reducir sólo a etiquetas de productos identificables (C, Python, PHP, ...). Pedirle a un novato que distinga entre Python, Python-2.7 y Python-2.x es demasiado.

Comment: @CandidMoe no creo que sea demasiado, opino que puede conseguirse. El sistema es bastante robusto y pensado para favorecer buenas etiquetas: sugiere automáticamente, ordena según uso, etc. Pero para ello hace falta que haya 2-3 usuarios por etiqueta grande que sea más o menos activo reetiquetando para fortalecerlo. Al fin y al cabo, buenas etiquetas y buenos títulos son fundamentales para que la gente pueda encontrar bien las cosas

Comment: aca, con la de linux estoy de acuerdo.. con el resto.. tengo mis dudas... animacion puede ser valida.. la de datatable.. ya no se que opinar con eso...

Comment: @gbianchi de acuerdo. ¿Cómo podríamos proceder? Si puedes marcar la de Linux y [tag:animación] y luego el resto lo discutimos específicamente en otra pregunta... como os vaya mejor

Comment: animacion y linux si... animated no me parece (habria que ver las preguntas) animate.css es una libreria... animación-css sera animate.css? voy arreglando eso.. y el resto abramos otro.. te parece?? porque es un tema datatables... @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: @gbianchi perfecto, muy agradecido. Marca si quieres en la pregunta (o en respuesta) las que corriges y el resto lo miramos en 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

las etiquetas

[linuxmint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linuxmint)
[linux-mint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint)

fueron fusionadas y ahora son sinonimos, con la primera como principal.

Tambien quedó como principal

[animación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animaci%c3%b3n)

y las dos siguientes fueron fusionadas a la anterior y son sinonimos ahora

[animation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation)
[animacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animacion)

[bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) fue arreglada en [Discusión sobre etiquetas duplicadas o mal escritas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4962/83..). y tenemos que ver el tema tables...

no toqué tampoco animate.css, habria que revisar las publicaciones a ver si se refieren a la libreria...

Comment: mmm lo de [tag:table] y [tag:tablas] sí podría hacerse