# Discusión sobre etiquetas duplicadas o mal escritas

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Quisiera presentarles este problema que a mi parecer es de una relevancia bastante importante.

Tenemos algunas etiquetas repetidas como por ejemplo [boostrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boostrap) y [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) (la primera está mal escrita) y otra que se le parece a esta es [boostraptable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boostraptable) que recomendaría su corrección a [bootstrap-table](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-table) o eliminarla del todo limitándolo a la etiqueta [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) ya que contamos con etiquetas como [table](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) y [tablas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablas) las cuales a mi parecer también podrían fusionarse.

Este tipo de etiquetas repetidas con el agravante de la mala escritura además de dañar el nivel de calidad del sitio obstaculiza el procedimiento de monitorización de las preguntas ocasionando un posible retraso en el tiempo de respuesta a preguntas que por error llevan una etiqueta como [boostrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boostrap) la cual es observada por una sola persona mientras que la de [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) al momento cuenta con 367 observadores.

Me gustaría proponer una corrección de las mismas por los motivos antes explicados y quizás incluso abrir un debate sobre si se pueden fusionar algunas de ellas para simplificar su monitoreo.

Comment: yo combinaria las etiquetas... alguien no esta de acuerdo??? por favor, en preguntas sobre etiquetas, hagamos de a una por pregunta!!!!

Comment: Es que no quería abrir tres preguntas. Pero si es necesario se hace.

Comment: la de tablas creo que ya esta abierta por otro lado...

Comment: Ya se había iniciado un debate al respecto por aquí: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4839/habr%c3%ada-que-hacer-tabla-rasa-con-las-etiquetas
Pero esta también abarca muchas etiquetas y no menciona sobre el error ortográfico de la etiqueta [tag:boostrap]

Comment: @gbianchi yo planteé varias preguntas y me curré bastante la lista hace varios meses. ¿Habéis revisado algo? Resulta bastante frustrante

Comment: te debo varias @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'... lo se...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listo!!! quedo solo [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)

Comment: ¿Te liberaste también de boostraptable?

Comment: oh yeah.. pero si ven cosas raras me avisan!

Comment: estos cambios solo pueden realizarlo usuarios diamantados? o los demás usuarios con n RP creo que tambien pueden no? tengo entendido que con solo eliminar la etiqueta de las preguntas y dejarla en 0 se estaría quemando su uso. Corríganme por favor

Comment: los usuarios diamantados pueden fusionar o crear sinonimos sin necesidad de una votacion... pero cualquier puede proponer sinonimos... y cualquiera puede borrar todas las etiquetas de un tipo, y el sistema luego solo las borra...